# MySQL Looping Through a Field in a Stored Procedure and Returning in the SAME result set

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to loop a SELECTED RESULT SET in a Stored Procedure depending on whatever number I specify as my parameter.

Example.

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE Say_ma_name(IN number INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_counter INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE v_name CHAR;
    SELECT name INTO v_name FROM Table WHERE id = number;
```

Now lets say the name SELECTED is 'Bob'.  I would like from here to have a generated RESULT SET that returns:

```
    Bob, Bob, Bob
```

The rest of my script looks something like this:

```
    REPEAT
        SELECT CONCAT_WS(',',v_name);
        SET v_counter = V_counter + 1;
    UNTIL v_counter > number END REPEAT;
END |
DELIMITER ;

CALL Say_ma_name(1);
```

For those of you following, this will return THREE(3) separate result sets, each with Bob in it.  I am trying achieve this all in just one result.  Regards.

Comment: If you have one 'Bob' in your table, why do you want to get result set of three 'Bob' records? Also, I do not see any relations between `number` in WHERE clause and `number` to count records.

Answer (score 0):

So you'll need to create an intermediate string value:

```
SET @result = '';
REPEAT
    SET @result = CONCAT(@result, ',');
    SET v_counter = V_counter + 1;
UNTIL v_counter > number END REPEAT;

SELECT TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM @result);
```

Comment: of course the *real* WTF is the fact that there appears to be no good reason to use the id value of the row and repeat the string that many times.